# Checking when value in array is 0 but not NULL C++

Tags: c++

I'm newbie and I need little help.
I tried different ways, but from what I can see NULL means 0 in c ++, so when want my (for example) int arr[4]=0, then it says that it's also NULL. Is there any way to see when value is 0 and not NULL (or empty?).

Comment: `NULL` and `nullptr` are a fancy way to spell `0` for pointers. There some minor differences between those spellings, but all of them represent the same pointer value (null), so you can't discern between them.

Comment: the only pointer in your example is arr, arr[4] is not a pointer but an integer value (that's hopefully inside the range of your array).

Comment: It is not possible to mark a value of an `int` as "empty".     The assignment `arr[0] = NULL` will assign `arr[0]` to be zero, not mark it as "empty".

Comment: `NULL` isn't part of c++, and I don't think that `int arr[4]=0` would compile, what's the intent there? If you can clarify your question, maybe in the process you could find an answer.

Comment: @PepijnKramer    `arr` is an array, not a pointer.   The name of an array can be used *as if* it is a pointer in some contexts but not others.   But that does not mean an array is a pointer, nor vice versa.

Comment: @MatG - `NULL` is a macro that expands as a null pointer constant.  It is in the standard header `<cstdlib>` in C++.

Comment: @Peter You are correct

Comment: An array is a data structure with a fixed size. E.g. use a std::vector instead which can change its size and can be tested for .size(). If you want the individual elements of a fixed size data structure be optionally empty, use std::optional<int> as data type within a data structure like std::array<std::optional<int>>. Alternatively (depending on your application) you can keep int as data type and define (by yourself) that a certain number, which you do not use elsewhere, e.g. -1 for otherwise positive integers, signifies empty.

Comment: NULL is the old (C) way for 'empty' pointers. nullptr is the more idiomatic and safe, modern C++ way. Both are specifically meant for pointers, not for int datatypes.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your specific use case? There are some solutions that may work for some use cases and not others. There's not a one-size-fits-all value for a null integer, but there may be values you can use depending on what "valid" data looks like.

Comment: A [example] would go a long way here. Make sure it compiles if I were to copy-paste it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for `std::optional`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> arr[] = { 10, 0, std::nullopt, -52 };

    for (auto i = 0U; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i])
        {
            std::cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << *(arr[i]) << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "arr[" << i << "] = std::nullopt" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
arr[0] = 10
arr[1] = 0
arr[2] = std::nullopt
arr[3] = -52
```

Comment: Looks like a perfect solution to an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a *null concept* for your data type (`int array[4]`), but you want `0` to be a valid (non-null) value. The null concept is useful when your variable is not guaranteed to hold valid data. You need a null concept if, for a variable `x`, you want to be able to ask the question *"does `x` contain a valid value?"*.

First, recognize that `NULL` is an implementation-defined way to represent a pointer that points at nothing. Here, implementation means "specific compiler". Usually, `NULL` is an integer constant equal to `0`, which in practice makes it ill-suited to differentiate from your otherwise-valid value of `0`.

TL;DR: I think you want to use `std::vector`, but you have several options available.

#### Null concept for `int`

Depending on what your data represents, you may be able to represent a null by selecting a value or range of values that are not valid for your specific use case, but otherwise representable using your data type.

Some example null concepts for `int` data type:

- **`0`--** is a perfectly fine null when `0` is not a valid value. The null test code is very clean as well: `if (x) { ... }`.
- **negative values--** You can select a specific negative value or the entire range of negative values. Or even a subrange of all negative values, although I've never seen this last one in practice. Generally the specific value of `-1` is used. The null test code looks like: `if (x >= 0) { ... }` or `if (x != -1) { ... }`.
- **extreme positive values--** You can select a very large number to represent the null concept. If a valid instance of your data will never reach this value. I recommend [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), which requires `#include <limits>`. The null test looks like: `if (x != std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) { ... }`

#### [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

When all possible values of your data type represent valid values, then you need to include extra overhead if you want to represent the null concept. `std::optional<T>` wraps any data type and is used specifically for the case where you need to represent invalid data. The access semantics looks very similar to accessing a pointer.

```
#include <optional>

void do_something(int);

int main() {
    std::optional<int> a; // default initialization is "empty"
    std::optional<int> b = 1; // can be assigned just as if it were the type

    if (a) { // You can check in a natural-feeling way if the data is valid
        do_something(*a); // and access the data as if it were a pointer
        do_something(a.value()); // or use std::optional<T>::value()
    }

    // If the data may be invalid, you must check before accessing
    // *a; // WRONG: throws an exception
    // a.value(); // WRONG: for the same reason

    // If you know for certain the data is valid, feel free to access it
    do_something(*b);

    // You can't access it entirely as if it were an int, dereferencing is necessary
    // int c = b + 2; // invalid, no overloaded operator+ for std::optional<int> type
    int c = *b + 2; // valid

    // An array of optionals looks similar to an array of ints
    std::optional<int> array[4]; // initialized as all empty
```

#### Just don't deal with invalid data at all

If your data doesn't necessarily need to exist until it is valid then you can use a variable size container to just... not have invalid data at all.

[`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is the go-to dynamically sized container in C++, and allows you to have just enough space to handle only the data you need. `std::vector<T>` also has many class methods that allow easy access to container information such as `std::vector<T>::size()` or iterators with `std::vector<T>::begin()` and `std::vector<T>::end()`.

```
#include <vector>

void do_something(int);

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data; // initially empty, no elements

    // you can add new values
    data.push_back(1); // vector contains { 1 }
    data.emplace_back(2); // vector contains { 1 , 2 }

    // looping is the same as with arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        do_something(data[i]);
    }

    // or you can use range-based for loops for cleaner looking code
    for (auto& d : data) {
        do_something(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is an array of pointers:

```
int* arr[10] = {};
```

Then here is how you check if an element is null:

```
if (arr[4] == nullptr)
```

And here is how you check if the pointed value is zero:

```
if (*arr[4] == 0) // note the *
```

Comment: This answer shows an array of pointer to ints, whereas the OP had an array of ints (if I understood correctly)

Comment: @PepijnKramer arr[4] is a pointer in this example, and *arr[4] dereferences that pointer. Otherwise the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Sebastian I am guessing OP wants an array of pointers, otherwise the use of the null pointer is unclear.